# PHP while true loop, sleep() function minimum time

Tags: php

I have a php function

```
<?php
while(true){
   sleep(2);
   echo 1;
}
?>
```

ask : Is it kill server?

Comment: What do you mean by "kill server"? I don't see that this will kill anything.

Comment: Depending on your PHP ini configuration, it will probably be killed after an amount of time has passed.  See https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: I mean "Server timeout".

Comment: @AlexBarker can you tell me a line name in php.ini ?

Comment: Servers are usually configured to time out after about 30 seconds. This doesn't have to do much with PHP, especially not with this one. What exactly do you mean? Your script is an infinite loop. If you request this file via web server, the web server will terminate it when the request times out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There are two possible answers to this question...

#### First

If by *kill* you mean does that one process *strain server resources* by itself, then the answer is no, since [`sleep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) is a system call [1] (*on linux implementations*) that removes the process from the CPU and restores it only after a system interrupt which is triggered by the scheduler when the timeout has lapsed. So the process is literally no longer consuming CPU cycles (*i.e. not using up server resources*) for as long as it's in a sleep state. In a CLI SAPI this might be fine or even desirable in some cases since you typically retain full control over when this script can be run and how many of them are run at a time.

#### Second

If you are in a web-facing environment, however (*i.e. this php script is initiated via an HTTP request to your web server*) then you have to consider the fact that you have a finite number of web-workers available to you. If the request is initiated say 30 times and you only have 30 workers available you now have all workers tied up infinitely and users can no longer make any requests to your web server. So in that sense you have actually *strained server resources*.

So be very careful whenever you have a `while(true)` loop. Ask yourself, is this really necessary? Most of the times it's not.

#### N.B.

By the way, it's also important to understand that time spent in external streams, of which sleep would be inclusive, is not counted against your [`max_execution_time`](https://www.php.net/info.configuration#ini.max-execution-time). So the 2 seconds spent in sleep don't count, but every time the process wakes up again then that time is added up. So yes, it is important to set `max_execution_time` to 0 if you wish for the process to continue running infinitely inside that loop. In the CLI interpreter this is 0 by default, but in most web SAPIs it has a default value of 30 seconds, because you usually don't want any web-facing requests to tie up your workers for that long.

[1] http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html

Comment: I'm using for a long polling system, while loop check if server have update and after select table. is it necessary ? do you have any better way to make long-polling?

Comment: Yes, I'd suggest [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or [HTTP/2 Server Push](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/04/guide-http2-server-push/) on the web-facing end instead of the inefficient re-initiating HTTP request technique. For backend polling it really depends on what you're doing. In the event of triggering a client push upon a specific database record update I'd suggest firing off a job into some kind of a queue or job manager that operates out-of-band from the web request and allows the client-push to happen disassociatively from the initiating process.

Comment: thanks, I'll try if long-polling will not work. regards.

Comment: No one is suggesting that long polling won't work. It simply works less efficiently.

Comment: what you mean about less efficiently? if is true, I have ask, why Facebook use long-polling?

Comment: Your question implies that because facebook uses it that it cannot be inefficient or that whatever facebook does is necessarily efficient. Neither of those implications are necessarily true. facebook can afford to make certain technical tradeoffs that work well for them that may not necessarily work well for you. When you're a $500 Billion company you can afford to sacrifice some efficiency for effectiveness where it may suit you. But when you're a one-man-band you can't really afford to blow up your $5/mo VPS.

Comment: Yes I know what you mean, but if we imagine 1 000 000 long-polling server, file name + rand(1,1000000).php send xhttp request, your longpolling work like facebook longpolling. what you think?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question. I think you're a bit hung up on the idea that long polling necessarily entails your specific implementation details outlined here, which is farthest removed from reality. Polling is merely the technique of polling (i.e. sending requests to the server) in successive intervals.  Long polling is a methodology of prolonging the polling mechanism to reuse the existing TCP connection. That's not what you're doing here at all. You're actually exasperating server resources by keeping a perfectly useful connection idle and therefore used inefficiently.

Comment: Just for reference point the reason facebook uses this archaic methodology of long-polling requests rather than a more efficient two-way pipe like a WebSocket is primarily rooted in **legacy**. Facebook built their messenger application long before WebSockets were a standard in HTTP. While they could have rebuilt their code to use a more modern approach they decided not to for infrastructure and reliability reasons that have more to do with business requirements rather than technical ones. Meaning, there is absolutely no technical justification for anyone building a new app today to do that.

Comment: So I strongly suggest you drop this absurd notion of trying to follow in facebook's footsteps under the misguided hypothesis that if facebook does it MUST be the right thing to do. Speaking strictly from a technical stand-point a long polling approach will fall flat on its face in a single node multi-tenancy infrastructure. Think about it like this. If a single user opened 15 tabs in their browser to your long-polling app and all you have are 15 web workers on your server, you just completely exhausted an entire server by **a single user**. That is a *grotesquely* inefficient use of resources.

Comment: Let me put it to you in another way that might be a lot clearer. Facebook has over a dozen data centers, each filled with tens of thousands (*if not hundreds of thousands*) of servers. StackOverflow, on the other hand, which uses WebSockets, runs on about **25 servers total**. StackOverflow can withstand tens of thousands of concurrent connections on a single node. Once you get into long polling you quickly start needing more & more servers. I can run a WebSocket server that handles 1K+ connections on a single **aws t2.micro** with 2 CPUs and 1GB of RAM. You can't do that with long polling.

Comment: At least not with a lot of engineering man power and some very clever hackery. Both of which I doubt you have.